# Samba 4 change password old enable

Tags: samba

I've a samba4 domain and I've changed user password but I've tried the old password and it still works!

My workaround was change the password twice with same new password.

Anyone know why this happens?

Comment: Welcome to the site. If a question was answered to your satisfaction, please don't add a notice to the title. Instead, klick on the (currently greyed-out) checkmark left of the answer you found most useful (which can be your own, after a certain embargo time) to [accept](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it - _this_ will indicate to the site that the problem is solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is disable pass history:

```
samba-tool domain passwordsettings set --history-length=0
```

Answer (score 1):

Samba tries to emulate AD and this is an AD feature, when you change the password, you can still use the old password for an hour.

Comment: Thanks Rowland....do you know a way to disable this feature?!